# How to looping data from multidimension array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i found something problem with looping data in multidimension array. i got error. **undefined $t** in my view. 
this my controller :

```
$dp[] = array(
        'id'                => $ft->idpr_order,
        'nor_order_pro'     => $ft->no_order_pro,
        'product_name'      => $ft->nama_produk,
        'sku'               => $ft->artikel,
        'brand'             => $ft->merk,
        'discount'          => $discft,
        'size'              => $ukr,
        'color'             => $wrn,
        'qty'               => $ft->qty,
        'price_before'      => $hg_before,
        'price_fix'         => $ft->harga_fix,
        );
    }

    $exp = explode('|', $resex);    
    $data_cs = array(
        'inv'      => $invoice,
        'tglOrdercs' => date('d F Y H:i:s'),
        'tglExp'   => $date_maju,
        'nmlkp'    => $nmlkpi,
        'almtkp'   => $address,
        'note'     => $note_ol,
        'kota'     => $city,
        'prov'     => $prov,
        'layanan'  => $exp[0],
        'etd'      => $exp[1],
        'tarif'    => $exp[2],
        'noTelp'   => $notelp271,
        'methode'  => $method,
        'bnk_option' => $banking_select,
        'cabang'   => $banking_inf_cab,
        'no_rek'   => $banking_inf_no,
        'an_bnk'   => $banking_inf_an,
        'subtotal' => $subt,
        'kode_pembayaran' => $code_unik,
        'total_belanja' => $tot_bel,
        'berat_total' => $tot_ber,
        'data_order' => $dp
     );
    $body = $this->load->view('em_info_notification_group/mail_order_for_admin',$data_cs,TRUE);
```

and this my view

```
<?php 
            foreach ($data_order as $data):
              if (is_array($data)):
                foreach ($data as $value):
                  if (is_array($value)):
                      foreach ($value as $t):
          ?>
          <tr> 
            <td class="yut" align="left" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
              <h4 style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><b><?php echo $t['product_name'];?></b></h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled" style="font-size: 12px; padding-left: 15px;margin-top: 0;">
                <li class="gf">SKU : <?php echo $t['sku'];?></li>
               <?php echo $t['color'];?>
               <?php echo $t['size'];?>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="yut" style="font-size: 14px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" align="center">
              <?php echo $t['qty'];?> pcs
            </td>
            <td class="yut" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;" align="right">  
              <span style="font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $t['price_before'];?><br><harga>Rp. <?php echo $t['price_fix'];?></harga><br><?php echo $t['discount'];?></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
                    endforeach;
                  endif;
                endforeach;
              endif;
            endforeach;
          ?>
```

in my view i got error. **undefined $t** in my view. actually the data I want to parse it to the admin template html. I have done various ways but nothing works

Comment: Check the posted answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your looping structure to:

```
    foreach ($data_order as $data):
      if (is_array($data)):
        foreach ($data as $t):
```

Regards,